# What does 'HTTP Response: 403 Forbidden' mean when trying to access Amazon's API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm building a simple Ruby on Rails application and am using the [Amazon Product Advertising API (amazon-ecs)](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) gem docs. Right now I am just trying to get a response from Amazon and I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error. This is the following code that I have so far:

```
Amazon::Ecs.options = {
  :AWS_access_key_id => '[myaccesskey]',       
  :AWS_secret_key => '[mysecretkey]'
}


res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('soccer books')
puts res.total_items
```

Expecting to see an integer with the number of responses but the code stops running and gives me an error.

I'm going exactly by the documentation so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: To put it into simple terms this is what is happening: http://httpstatusdogs.com/403-forbidden ;). As the caption says on the photo:  authenticating will make no difference. So i highly doubt it has anything to do with authentication.

Comment: @David what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: from looking on the github repo it expects you to specify an associate_tag ` :associate_tag => '[your associate tag]'`

Comment: @David I noticed that too and added the associates tag, but am still getting the same error. Just wish there was more documentation on debugging this.

Comment: @David it could still be an authentication issue.  HTTP 403 implies nothing about authentication in general, only that *HTTP authentication* isn't being solicited by the server, as it is with a 401.  AWS never uses HTTP auth, and invalid credentials usually will cause a 403.  There is usually an xml response body that gives more detail, but many users don't know to check it, or how to access it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I see that make sense now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

```
# Set the default options; options will be camelized and converted to REST request parameters.
# associate_tag and AWS_access_key_id are required options, associate_tag is required option
# since API version 2011-08-01. 
#
# To sign your request, include AWS_secret_key.
```

So it seems like you should just add `associate_tag` option, since it is required option.

More about associate tag: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AssociateTag.html

Comment: Even when I add the associate tag it still gives me the same error, not sure why I'm getting this error.